My searchName function works but throws an exception everytime I use it, what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?
I'm making a banking program for an assignment and I'm required to make 2 search functions, one to search for an account using the account number, and the other to search for accounts using first names. The number search works perfectly fine, it's just the name search that isn't working. Here is the code I'm using:
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char name[30];

    struct node* NEXT;
}nodeT;

char* searchName(nodeT* top);

void main() {
    nodeT* headPtr = NULL;

    nodeT test;

    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("%s", test.name);

    printf("%s", searchName(headPtr));
}
char* searchName(nodeT* top)
{
    nodeT* temp = top;
    char searchName[30];
    int found = 0;

    printf("Search name: ");
    fgets(searchName, 29, stdin);

    found = 0;

    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(searchName, temp->name) == 0)
        {
            printf("Name: %s", temp->name);

            found = 1;
            return;
        }

        temp = temp->NEXT;
    }

    if (found == 0)
    {
        printf("Your search was not found\n");
    }
}

Output:
Name: example
Search name: example
Name: example

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAA42DAC87 (ucrtbased.dll) in MRE.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000066.

It will print out the results of the query but then stop the program. How can I fix this?
I have to assume that the issue is with return but I'm not sure.
I had fgets there twice originally because it would skip the input.

headPtr = NULL; followed by searchName(headPtr) – what do you expect to happen?

Also, you say that searchName() returns a char * but you have a return; that doesn't return anything and missing a return at the end.  The subsequent printf() is undefined behavior.

@AKX The while() loop guards against that.

@AllanWind Guards against what?

@AKX Deference of a NULL pointer.  To  answer to your original question, op should expect a prompt for a "Search name:" and a string being read and the output "Your search was not found\n".

@AllanWind Yes, and I never mentioned a possible null pointer deref – I was pointing out the logic issue of never assigning anything to headPtr before passing it forward...

What have you done to try to debug this code? Can you share what you’ve learned and what hypotheses you have about where the issues might be?

What compiler do you use? Didn't it warn you about returnin from a non-void function withtout returning a vaue? Do not ignore warnings. They are here for you. Most of the time, the compiler knows better than you.
